# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1920

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1920 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there is atleast one entry. The second note does not have a year in the margin so I do not know if it is for 1920 or 1921. Perhaps the transcription will give us context.

Here is the one confirmed note for 1920:

[image]

As you can see, this is typed text and thus quite clear. However, I can't make out some of the letters to the right hand side and **Perfenecer** comes up as an unknown word in my word processor.

This is the transcription so far:

> Con motivo de la nueva distribución dada al Inxxx to por R.O.C. 30
> Abril ([D.O. núm. 100](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=11502)) pasa este ind [Individuo ?] Perfenecer al
> 18 Tercio causando baja en este 4 en fin de Mayo.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I have linked to the relevant bulletin but I am not sure which specific article in it relates to this note and why.

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the answer provided:

> As a result of the new distribution given to the Institute by R.O.C.
> 30 April (D.O. no. 100), this individual became a member of the 18th
> Tercio and was discharged at the end of May.
>
> The Major Commander

The "document" that we are working through has the heading **4<sup>o</sup> TERCIO** and now he is moving to the **18<sup>o</sup> TERCIO**. I wonder what the significance of this transition was? Does the linked bulletin provide any insight at all?

---

#### Bulletin

I tried to find a reference to the **18th Tercio** and I found this on page 3 which is tied in with Cordoba: (which would also be correct):

[image]

I don't really know the significance of all those numbers etc. but I figure that my great-grandfather was one of those statistics there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says [**pertenecer**](https://dle.rae.es/pertenecer), which means *to belong* in a regiment or any similar group.

So it is saying that it moves into the 18º Tercio.

All together, it seems to be saying:

> Con motivo de la nueva distribución dada al **Instituto** por R.O.C. 30 Abril (D.O. núm. 100) pasa este ind [individuo ✅] a **pertenecer** al 18º Tercio causando baja en este 4º en fin de Mayo.
>
> EL COMNDTE [Comandante] MAYOR

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not sure on those words! I have updated the question with my proposed translation and observations.

Comment: I just updated the question with my findings in the bulletin that pertain to the **18th tercio**.