# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1936

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1936 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there is one entry. This is the final entry in the document. I wanted to jump forward to do this one for a reason.

I contacted the Civil Guard and they informed me that my great-grandfather actually retired on 31 January 1936 at the age of 54. So I wanted to confirm this by transcribing the final note now (for my curiosity).

Here is the note:

[image]

Here is my transcribed text thus far:

> Continúo prestando sus servicios en la comandancia de Córdoba hasta
> fin del mes de enero que según orden del ministerio de la xxx fecha 8
> de xxx saceta 14 xxx caya en la xxx por pase xxx de retrado.
>
> Córdoba 4 Febrero 1936
>
> El Jefe del Detall

And here is my transcribed text so far:

> He continued to serve in the cordoba command until the end of january
> which according to the order of the ministry of the xxx dated 8 of
> xxx, gazette 14 xxx, was transferred to the xxx by pass xxx of
> retrado.
>
> Cordoba 4 February 1936
>
> The Chief of Details

I understand that **retrado** has to do with retirement. But for some reason DeepL has messed up again.

Thanks for confirming the transcription and translation.

---

### Translation

Here is the translation based on the provided answer:

> He continued to serve in the Cordoba command until the end of January,
> when, by order of the Ministry of the Interior on the 8th of that
> month (Gaceta nº 14), he was discharged from his post as a retired
> officer.
>
> Córdoba 4 February 1936
>
> The Detall Office Cheif

---

#### Note

I notice by the final stamp that at the time of his retirement he was in the 18<sup>o</sup> Tercio so I am going to assume that for the remaining of his service (from [1920](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39507/28260) onward) that he remains there. But we will see as we complete the notes in the document for 1920 - 1935.

---

#### Photo

The comment made by @gparis got me to thinking:

> Regarding this note, it may be of interest to check out this D.O. of
> 15 January 1936. Your great-grandfather's name appears in a list of
> civil guards to be retired. According to this list, he was going to
> fix his residence in **Puente Genil** (Córdoba).

I looked through the photos my mother gave me and here is one of him with one of my mums sisters (blurred for privacy). It is **dated 2 Enero 1954** and I notice the bottom right says **Puente Genil**! Didn't realise the significance of those words when mum gave me the photo.

[image]

---

#### Related Question ([History](https://history.stackexchange.com/))

- https://history.stackexchange.com/q/65835/51962

Comment: Side point: I have an identity card of my great-grandfather with the heading *2o Cuerpo de Ejercito - Guardia Civil*. What confuses me is that it is dated *16 de Mayo de 1946*. That is 6 years after this retirement. I may ask a separate question about this but for now I have sent an email to the Civil Guard for an explanation.

Comment: Well, the II Spanish Republic goverment took actions to reduce its armed forces. Their new laws favoured retirements like your ancestor's. Maybe he rejoined the Guardia Civil during the Civi War that started in july of that year. Or maybe in his situation of retired he still was considered part of the army for a set of years.

Comment: Great translation. You've got a typo in the last line, Cheif should be Chief.

Comment: @RubioRic I have corrected **Chief** in my document. I assume **Gaceta** is **Gazette**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Regarding this note, it may be of interest to check out [this D.O. of 15 January 1936](https://bibliotecavirtual.defensa.gob.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=15373). Your great-grandfather's name appears in a list of civil guards to be retired. According to this list, he was going to fix his residence in Puente Genil (Córdoba).

Comment: Thanks @gparis! I would never have known about that bulletin. I see him listed on page 7. I realised I had a photo of my great-grandfather with Puente Genil mentioned on it. I added it to the question as background info.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I found it with the following google search: `"miguel torres jimenez" site:www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es`. Unfortunately, it's the only result that appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions

> Continúo prestando sus servicios en la comandancia de Córdoba hasta
> fin del mes de enero que según orden del Ministerio de la **Gobernación** fecha 8
> de **dicho mes** **(Gaceta nº** 14) **causa baja** en la **misma** por **pase a situación** de **retirado**.
>
> Córdoba 4 Febrero 1936
>
> El Jefe del Detall

I don't think that detall can be translated to detail. That word is not recognized in a military sense in our main dictionary, the DLE. 
According to the [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detall)

> **DETALL** (**D**epartamento **E**stadístico de **T**rámite **A**dministrativo de **L**ibros y
> **L**istados) es la oficina de archivo, partes y papeleo de un cuerpo
> militar de tropa.
>
> También se llama **oficial de detall**, o simplemente detall, a cierto
> tipo de oficial militar subalterno, habitualmente encargado de labores
> burocráticas y administrativas, como el despacho de correspondencia.
> También se conoce como oficina administrativa, donde se realiza la
> documentación resultante del manejo del recurso humano, como son hojas
> de actuación, expediente de cuerpo y otros de carácter legal.

More or less it says that the Detall Office is some kind of Human Resources and Archive office inside a military corp. I don't know the exact word for such thing in the English or North American armies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and extra information. I have updated the question with the new translation which is now very understandable. For now I have used *The Detall Office Cheif* unless another suggestion is put forward. And for some reason it did not translate *Gaceta*.