# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1920 or 1921 - Not sure of year

Tags: identificación-de-término

I have this note in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records and is in between the 1920 and 1921 notes. So it is ambiguous as to which year it relates.

Going on recent notes for 1919 I am going to assume it is for 1920. It might be come apparent after the the note is correctly transcribed and translated.

The note:

[image]

As you can see, no year in the margin is evident (to me). This is the transcribed text so far:

> En la revista de Junio [?] en la procedencia anterior causo al xxx en
> fe. [fecha ?] 18º Junio en el puesto de Obejo fin el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

---

#### Translation

Based on the answer provided this is the translation:

> In the June review of the previous provenance, he joined this 18th
> tercio. He finished the year at the Obejo post.
>
> The Major Commander

This confirms that it was for 1920 because it is a direct follow on from this [June 1920](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39507/28260) note. But, is the word **provenance** correct in the translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions:

> En la revista de Junio **de** la procedencia anterior causó **alta en
> éste 18º tercio**. En el puesto de Obejo **finió** el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated the question with the translation and my observations.